# Should I use the subject?

Tags: logic

> Ice melted and then froze.

Ice is already frozen water. So it can’t freeze. So shouldn’t it change into this?

> Ice melted and the melted ice froze.

Comment: I'd say *Ice melted and then **refroze*** is far more natural, but [according to this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=melted+and+froze%2Cmelted+and+refroze%2Cmelted+and+re-froze&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmelted%20and%20froze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmelted%20and%20refroze%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmelted%20and%20froze%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmelted%20and%20refroze%3B%2Cc0) ***refroze*** has only really come to prominence in recent decades. Whatever - it's the most common version ***today***.

Comment: But note that "Ice is already frozen water" is only true *while it's frozen*. The fact that it *was* frozen is a bit irrelevant ***after it melted***.

Comment: "Ice melted and the melted ice froze." - this is awkward and repetitive. 'The ice melted and then froze again' is much better. Sometimes elegance is more important than strict logic.

Comment: @Jennifer: What makes you think NGrams aren't "trustworthy"? Sure, there will be (some, not many) OCR errors in very old texts. But in this case the usage we're looking at barely existed until 50 hyears ago, so almost all the books indexed would have already been in "proofread" electronic format. Do you think Google employs software engineers to massage the results obtained by indexing millions of books?

Comment: The corpus of texts Google has indexed is limited, and Google itself is a company known for all sorts of pernicious manipulation. While I can't say I have evidence of them manipulating NGrams for whatever reason, I don't think such measurements should be relied upon wholeheartedly, either.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you think the person you are speaking to has the logical abilities of Mr Spock, combined with the intelligence of a very stupid worm!

There is no need to say "... and the the melted ice froze."

There are lots of examples like this:

> He lit a fire.

(logically it wasn't a fire until after he lit it...)

> He is writing a novel.

(But it isn't a novel yet...)

Fortunately  you can depend people not being mere calculating machines and sentences like "He lit a fire" are completely understandable. Indeed such sentences are so simple that they will exist in almost identical form in pretty much every human language.

There is nothing special about English.  G-Translate offers

冰融化了，然后冻结了。
बर्फ पिघली और फिर जम गई।
Toddodd y rhew ac yna rhewodd.
La glace a fondu puis a gelé.

Now English does offer the verb "refreeze" that can help. Or you can help with "again"

> The ice will melt by mid-morning, but refreeze at night as temperatures drop below zero.